# Access database outside of vagrant box as user

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Homestead and have created multiple databases. I now wanted to use a new username/password combination for each database I create. I did it like this

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb CHARACTER SET utf8;
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';
```

Now, when I access my vagrant box via `vagrant ssh` and then use this command

```
$ mysql -utestuser -ptestpassword
```

I can connect to the database. However, when trying to access the database from outside (like via a client (Sequel Pro)) I can't connect to the database with the created user.

I can, however, connect with my "base account" homestead:secret. With the homestead user I can access every database, however I wanted to use my newly created user. How would I achieve this?

The error that comes from Sequel Pro is

> Access denied for user 'testuser'@'10.0.2.2' (using password: YES)

This is the db connection config

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also grant the access to the outside user:

```
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'10.0.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testuser'@'10.0.2.2';
```

Comment: Thanks! So I have to create both users?

Comment: You can also use a wildcard for the host part of the user: CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testuser'@'%';    - In this case you create only one user which can access the database from any host